# Object File format on iOS (getting SHA512 hash of installed app)

Tags: ios, hash, cryptography

Is there a way that I can know the hash all or part of an iOS app's executable file, prior to submitting my app for approval?

Would it be possible to include a magic constant in my app, so I could use its approximate position as a starting point for taking a SHA512 hash of most of the executable file?  I would like to add additional executable verification mechanisms to my app.

EDIT: After some searching on the Apple Developer site, I've run across the Mach-O File Format specification.

Comment: Do you want to check your application's own executable? This is hackable quite easily - if one can change the code, he can as well change the hash validation part. 

What particular threats do you want to handle?

Comment: Pick some honeypot code to checksum, and hide the hash result(s) someplace seemingly unimportant (random padding bytes in the apps high scores message packet or something).  Sure someone can easily hack this out, but why would the even think to look there?

Comment: @Eugene - Yes, I want to check my own executable.  Actually, the encryption key for the Javascript code (code itself is encrypted) of the 2nd half of the operation I want to protect is based on the hash of the executable + a separate IV.  There are also some other protections that I can't discuss here, but they are based on cryptographic hashes, procedurally generated obfuscation, and timing of execution by a server.

Answer (score 0):

Apple encrypts portions of the executable file, so any file hash prior to submission is likely to be invalid on a distributed app.

What you might be able to do is hash/checksum portions of the app as it executes in memory, by getting live function pointers and using them as start addresses.